# Email alert when LSF job array is finished running

Tags: lsf

I'm submitting a large-ish job array that might take a few hours to run (but might also fail with an error a few minutes in), and I'd like to get an email when it's done. If I don't set the `-oo` flag on `bsub` to a file, it will send me an email when each job in the array is done, but I'd rather not have to count a zillion emails to figure out when the whole array is through.

Is there an option in `bsub` that will allow me to specify an action to occur when all the jobs are finished, or do I have to hack my way around it in bash?

Answer (score 2):

There's no feature for this exact use case.  But you could have a dependent job that does send an email.

```
bsub -oo ... -J "myArray[1-10]" ...; bsub -w "done(myArray)" ...
```